# Masking credit-card input field in Cybersource Flex Microform

Tags: microformats, cybersource

In my project, I'm using Cybersource Flex Microform for Credit Card validations, but unable to mask the entered number on blur or key-up.

I am using the 0.4.0 version of the Flex Microform API and in the options object, I'm giving `inputType: "password"`.

```
window.FLEX.microform(
        {
          keyId: kid,
          keystore: keystore,
          container: '#cardNumber-container',
          label: '#cardNumber-label',
          styles: {
            input: {
              'font-size': '16px'
            }
          },
          encryptionType: 'rsaoaep256',
          inputType: 'password'
        },
        function(setupError, microformInstance) {
         // credit card on blur event functionality
        }
)
```

Still in the field, the input type is coming as the default "tel", but not as "password".

Comment: Does this have something to do with Microform**ats**?

Comment: inputType is not an part of the options Object so is ignored. See http://apps.cybersource.com/library/documentation/dev_guides/hosted_flex/0_4_0/flex_microform_0_4_0.pdf#page=27 for available options. You can subscribe to events within the microform, maybe you should listen for the blur event, then somehow hide the card #?

Comment: Hmm, thats an option, but user should still be able to go back to the field to update it.

And no, its not about Microformats.

As I saw somewhere, in version 0.1.0, inputType was there but in the latest version docs its not there. So there is some issue with other types of input fields I guess.